# Can I delete ASP.NET authentication cookie (.ASPXAUTH) using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms-authentication

Can I delete ASP.NET authentication cookie (.ASPXAUTH) using JavaScript? I would like to implement Sign Out functionality on my ASP.NET/JavaScript mobile application without a roundtrip to the server. However, this approach does not work for some reason.

```
document.cookie = '.ASPXAUTH=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

What should I do?

Thank you.

UPDATE: Okay, I read about a HttpOnly cookies, and it is the very case. In order to make the cookie not a HttpOnly, add the following line to web.config (system.web section):

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="false"/>
```

UPDATE: The method above does not work -- ASP.NET simply ignores the instruction. I ended up doing this hack in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cookieName = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
    if (Response.Cookies.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (string s in Response.Cookies.AllKeys)
        {
            if (s == cookieName)
            {
                Response.Cookies[cookieName].HttpOnly = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say you want to log out on the server as well, in order to clean up session state and such.

Comment: Well, I do not use Session state since it is a JavaScript client application. I use the server part for authentication and REST API.

Comment: @Alex Avrutin Thanks for a quick update:). You could post it as an answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: However, I still have to figure out how to make the cookie not HttpOnly.

Comment: That's a pretty clever way of handling log out. Still wondering about security but worth an upvote.

Comment: As long as you aren't using third party scripts, this *might* be ok, but once you start using them, or if , there's plenty of ways to copy that cookie value elsewhere, and thus allow other people to authenticate as your users In fact, that's talked about here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html

Comment: I am building a dating site, but a banking application, so this is a tolerable solution. Moreover, MVC3 does a good job of sanitizing user input.

Comment: Your problem may arise from a CookiePath that does not match - late answer, but may affect others. If you set an empty cookie with a wrong Path, ASP.NET will still see the old (authenticated) cookie.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to delete the cookie in order to signout the user, just set the "expires" value to yesterday, and BOOM, the user has been loggedout.

Consider this very helpful blog post: [Using cookies in Javascript part 1](http://www.markusnordhaus.de/2012/01/20/using-cookies-in-javascript-part-1/)

Comment: Thank you, but if the cookie is HttpOnly I won't be able even read it,  and I won't be able to modify 'expires' value.